# QT and Swing not acceptin the cursor theme of GNOME 3.14

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, theme, qt, cursor

I switched from Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity to OpenSuse 13.2 with GNOME 3.14 desktop.
The problem is when I change the cursor theme, GTK and Java SWT apps accepts the new theme while Java Swing and QT still on the old theme.
I changed the theme using Gnome Tweak Tool.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing `/usr/share/icons/default/index.theme`. You need to change the line:

```
Inherits=<something>
```

to:

```
Inherits=<name of cursor theme you are using>
```

For example, I'm using a theme called Openzone Ice Slim, so that line looks like this for me:

```
Inherits=Openzone Ice Slim
```

That will change a default fallback cursor theme for all users, and I think there is the file with the same name in `~/.icons/default/` which will change the default cursor per user.

Comment: The folder `default` doesn't exist in `/usr/share/icons` so I created it , but nothing changed. Also the folder `~/.icons/default` doesn't exist, I created it but nothing changed

Comment: I assume you also created the index.theme file in those folders. What do they look like? For me they are two lines long: first line - `[icon theme]` second line - `Inherits=Openzone Ice Slim`

Comment: I did, yet it didn't change anything. P.S.: I logged out then logged in after creating these files